# Why does an enum's variable name have to after the enumerated values in a C++ class?

Tags: c++, enums

If I use the first option, defining an enum normally, line 4 throws an error saying expected unqualified-id. Why is it that the enum variable name have to come after for this to work?

```
class Machine {
    enum state {ON, OFF}; // need to use "enum {ON, OFF} state;"
public:
    Machine() {state = ON;} // error here
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
enum state {ON, OFF};
```

defines an `enum` named `state`. `state` is a name of the type and no variable is declared here.

```
enum {ON, OFF} state;
```

defines a variable `state` whose type is the anonymous `enum`.